# Adding element to beginning of list, without creating a new list

Tags: list, prolog

I want to add [Startline, Assumption, assumption] to the beginning of list CheckedProof (without creating a new list).
Why doesn't this first code snippet give the same result for CheckedProof as the one where I just use append? Is it possible to yield the same result by just using append?

```
updateList([Element|List1], Element).
updateList(List1, Element):- !,
updateList([Element|List1], Element),!.

updateList(CheckedProof, [Startline, Assumption, assumption]).
```

```
append(CheckedProof, [], TemporaryCheckedProof)
append([[Startline, Assumption, assumption]], [TemporaryCheckedProof], CheckedProof).
```

Answer (score 1):

A Prolog list is by definition a compound term with two arguments. The first argument is the first element of the list, and the second argument is the rest of the list.

Prolog provides the notation `List = [H|T]` where you have a list `List` that has a first element `H` and the rest of the list in `T`.

In other words, you don't have to do anything special to add an element at the front of an existing list. Here:

```
?- Old = [a,b,c], New = [hello|Old].
Old = [a, b, c],
New = [hello, a, b, c].
```

Not sure what you are doing in your updateList predicate but it seems unnecessary.